# Proof of theorems (First Order Logic)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Considering the list of axioms:

$(A1)$ - All Tautologies.

$(A2)$ - $(\forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta)) $.

$(A3)$ - $(\forall x \alpha) \rightarrow [\alpha]^{t}_{x} $ if x is free for t in $\alpha$.

$(A4)$ - $\alpha \rightarrow (\forall x \alpha) $ if x is not free in $\alpha $.

$(A5)$ - $ x = x$

$(A6)$ - $(x=y) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ if $\beta$ if obtained by substitution of at least one occurrence of x free for y in $\alpha$.

I am trying to write a proof for some theorems. However, I am a little confused.

$ \vdash (\forall x_1(R_1^1(x_1) \lor R_2^1(x_1))) \rightarrow (R_2^1(x_1) \lor R_1^1(x_1))  $

For this one, could I use (A3), given that $\forall x_1$ on the left side of $\rightarrow$?

$ \vdash R_1^1(c_1) \rightarrow (R_1^1(c_2) \rightarrow  (R_1^1(c_1) \land R_1^1(c_2))) $

For this one, could I use the tautology $\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow(\alpha \land \beta))$, given that $R_1^1(c_1)$ is the same relational symbol, but applied to different constants?

$ \vdash \forall x_1(\forall x_2(R_1^1(x_1) \rightarrow (R_1^1(x_2) \rightarrow R_1^1(x_1))))$

Same question as before (combining the first ones), could I use the tautology $\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$ and then (A4)?

Answer (score 2):

First: Yes, though you have to combine (A3) with a tautology in order to get to swap the $R_2^1$ and $R_1^1$ disjuncts in the conclusion.

Second: Yes, this is an instance of (A1).

Third: No, (A3) will let you *remove* a $\forall$ from something you've already proved, not *add* it. In fact I'm almost sure your axioms are not enough to prove this, if all you have is Modus Ponens. Specifically, the axioms would all be true under a variant semantics where $\forall x\alpha$ always evaluates to false when $x$ is free in $\alpha$ (and MP preserves this truth). Since your goal is *not* true in this that variant semantics, it can't be proved.

Are you sure you don't have a separate Generalization rule in addition to your axioms and MP?

Comment: Sorry, i meant (A4) on that one, will edit. So, even with A4, I can't use it there, do I need the Generalization Theorem (GT) on that one? Considering the first, (A3) should change $x_1$ to $x_1$, is that correct?

Comment: @LuizS.: I'm not exactly sure what your "Generalization Theorem" says, but if it says what it sounds like it ought to, then it _is not true_ if all you have is tha axioms you have shown here plus MP.

Comment: It says: Let $\Gamma$ be a subset of formulas of a first order logic language such that the variable x is not free in all formulas of $\Gamma$. Then $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$ whenever $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \alpha$

Comment: @LuizS.: Ah, that looks true, but it goes in the wrong direction -- it _also_ requires you already to have proved $\forall x\alpha$ before it applies. (In fact what it states is just a simple application of A3 with $t=x$).

Comment: So I can't use it directly on the third case?

Comment: @LuizS.: No -- I strongly suspect you must have misquoted or forgotten something here. (For example when you wrote "whenever" above, did your source actually say "if and only if"? That would yield a claim you can use, but on the other hand I don't think it would be _true_).

Comment: These are the axioms presented by Enderton (A Mathematical Introduction to Logic). There, Generalization Theorem says that If $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ and x do not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$, is that different for what I've said before? Here, $\Gamma$ would be $\emptyset$ ?Thanks.

Comment: @LuizS.: What you said before was that if $\Gamma\vdash\forall x\phi$ then $\Gamma\vdash \phi$. I'm curious how he proves that theorem -- it is true for the usual first-order logic, but (as I keep saying) the rules you have quoted here do not seem to be strong enough for it to be true in _this_ system.